# jsPlumb multiple containment are not working together. is this bug?

Tags: jsplumb, containment

I have following HTML

```
<div id="leftpanel">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

I am adding **draggable** through JS dynamically. And using following JS code to make them draggable.

```
jsPlumb.draggable($("#top .draggable"),{containment:"#top"});
jsPlumb.draggable($("#middle .draggable"),{containment:"#middle"});
jsPlumb.draggable($("#bottom .draggable"),{containment:"#bottom"});
```

It shows me **draggble** in right containers. But when I star dragging, it suddenly moves selected draggable into **top** container. And when I drag it outside of **top** container it don't let me.

I have tried setting position of **draggable** to : relative,absolute. But it dint solve the problem .

**Edit**:
if I use

```
$("#divId").draggable({containment:container});
```

it works fine. But connections don't get dragged along with dvs. If I do following

```
jsPlumb.draggable($("#divId"),{containment:container});
```

then connections move along with divs but above mentioned problems occurrs ie div automatically moves to top conteiner.

Comment: Reported on jsplumb github as an [issue](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/issues/208)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8AgQD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your jsfiddle you're not using jquery.jsPlumb-xxx-min.js